# Extract strings from columns using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to extract the following strings from the title column and append to a new column named `hazard_extract` like in the below example.

```
test = {'title': ['Other', 'Microbiological - Listeria', 'Extraneous Material', 'Chemical', 'Chemical - Histamine', 'Labelling, Other'], 'hazard_extract':['Other', 'Microbiological', 'Extraneous Material', 'Chemical', 'Chemical', 'Labelling']}
example = pd.DataFrame(test)
example
```

```
    title                       hazard_extract
0   Other                       Other
1   Microbiological - Listeria  Microbiological
2   Extraneous Material         Extraneous Material
3   Chemical                    Chemical
4   Chemical - Histamine        Chemical
5   Labelling, Other            Labelling
```

However, I am using the code below - if the string does not have a `-` or `,` it does not extract the string. In this case, how can I extract both words as in `Extraneous Material` and a single word as in `Chemical` or `Other`?

```
example['hazard_extract'] = example['title'].str.extract(r'^(.*?),? ')
```

```
    title                       hazard_extract
0   Other                       NaN
1   Microbiological - Listeria  Microbiological
2   Extraneous Material         Extraneous
3   Chemical                    NaN
4   Chemical - Histamine        Chemical
5   Labelling, Other            Labelling
```

Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: so if there is a dash/comma, you want the part before the dash/comma; otherwise you want the full original string?

Answer (score 1):

No need for a complicated regular expression:

```py
import pandas as pd

test = {'title': ['Other', 'Microbiological - Listeria', 'Extraneous Material', 'Chemical', 'Chemical - Histamine', 'Labelling, Other']}
example = pd.DataFrame(test)
print(example)
print()
example['hazard_extract'] = example['title'].str.split(' -|,').str[0]
print(example)
```

```
                        title
0                       Other
1  Microbiological - Listeria
2         Extraneous Material
3                    Chemical
4        Chemical - Histamine
5            Labelling, Other

                        title       hazard_extract
0                       Other                Other
1  Microbiological - Listeria      Microbiological
2         Extraneous Material  Extraneous Material
3                    Chemical             Chemical
4        Chemical - Histamine             Chemical
5            Labelling, Other            Labelling
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest will be to use `split`

```py
example['title'].str.split(r'[-,]').str[0].str.strip()
```

```
0                  Other
1       Microbiological 
2    Extraneous Material
3               Chemical
4              Chemical 
5              Labelling
```

Comment: maybe add `.str.strip()`?

Comment: I was thinking about that but since OP needs the first element and `-` `,` comes right after the first word, though not required

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
example['title'].str.extract(r'^(\w*\s*\w*)\s*[\,\-]?.*')
```